# Mac for MS Word 2016 Sidebar

Tags: ms-office

How can I control what appears in the side bar. I have a large document, over 600 pages, with style sheets for the various headings. A group of people are working on the document, but I have control of the document. People copy and paste into the document which seems to be causing the problems because then the style sheets are different.

Even after I go through the document to change the style sheets to what they should be, the sidebar is a disaster.